# Data on Use of Tax Preparer?

Tags: data-request, taxes

Is there a data set for the U.S. that summarizes the use of tax preparers to complete / file tax returns by income of the filer?

Federal Form 1040 has fields for tax preparer information, but not sure if statistics on usage is made available or broken out by the income of the filer that uses them.

Comment: The only data I could find was http://www.irs.gov/uac/Newsroom/More-Taxpayers-Filing-from-Home-Computers-in-2014--Many-Taxpayers-Eligible-to-Use-Free-File which is pretty out of date but it's better than nothing? :)